# Splitting HTML Content Into Sentences, But Keeping Subtags Intact

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, nlp, text-segmentation

I'm using the code below to separate all text within a paragraph tag into sentences. It is working okay with a few exceptions. However, tags within paragraphs are chewed up and spit out. Example:

```
<p>This is a sample of a <a href="#">link</a> getting chewed up.</p>
```

So, **how can I ignore tags such that I could just parse sentences and place span tags around them and keep , , etc...tags in place?** Or is it smarter to somehow walk the DOM and do it that way?

```
// Split text on page into clickable sentences
$('p').each(function() {
    var sentences = $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(/(((?![.!?]['"]?\s).)*[.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g, 
                 '<span class="sentence">$1</span>$3');
    $(this).html(sentences);
});
```

I am using this in a Chrome extension content script; which means that the javascript is injected into any page that it comes in contact with and parses up the `<p>` tags on the fly. Therefore, it needs to be javascript.

Comment: So you are saying that the code that you have works fine, but you want to know if there are other ways to achieve the same? I don't really follow what you want, or what the problem is.

Comment: Bolded my question for clarity. I need to do what I'm doing right now, but keep all tags in place within the <p> tags that I'm searching through, so images, links, etc...stay intact.

Comment: Edited my question as well to reflect the fact that I'm using this in a chrome extension content script.

Comment: So what are you expecting for something like this? '<p>This is a sample of a "." inside  <strong>some element. What</strong> is your expected result?</p>'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Wow @AdamShiemke, that was an un...believable...post. Thank you for helping me see the light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Soapbox

We could craft a regex to match your specific case, but given this is HTML parsing and that your use case hints that any number of tags could be in there, you'd be best off using the DOM or using a product like [HTML Agility (free)](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

## However

If you're just looking to pull out the inner text and not interested in retaining any of the tag data, you could use this regex and replace all matches with a null

`(<[^>]*>)`

[image]
[image]

## Retain sentence as is including subtags

- `((?:<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>).*?</p>)` - retain the paragraph tags and entire sentence, but not any data outside the paragraph
- `(?:<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)(.*?)(?:</p>)` - retain just the paragraph innertext including all subtags, and store sentence into group 1
- `(<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)(.*?)(</p>)` - capture open and close paragraph tags and the innertext including any sub tags

Granted these are PowerShell examples, the regex and replace function should be similar

```
$string = '<img> not this stuff either</img><p class=SuperCoolStuff>This is a sample of a <a href="#">link</a> getting chewed up.</p><a> other stuff</a>'

Write-Host "replace p tags with a new span tag"
$string -replace '(?:<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)(.*?)(?:</p>)', '<span class=sentence>$1</span>'

Write-Host
Write-Host "insert p tag's inner text into a span new span tag and return the entire thing including the p tags"
$string -replace '(<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)(.*?)(</p>)', '$1<span class=sentence>$2</span>$3'
```

Yields

```
replace p tags with a new span tag
<img> not this stuff either</img><span class=sentence>This is a sample of a <a href="#">link</a> getting chewed up.</span
><a> other stuff</a>

insert p tag's inner text into a span new span tag and return the entire thing including the p tags
<img> not this stuff either</img><p class=SuperCoolStuff><span class=sentence>This is a sample of a <a href="#">link</a> 
getting chewed up.</span></p><a> other stuff</a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify just a bit, maybe incorporating your answer with my regex?

Comment: It looks like you want to pull the sentence string out from the tags and substitute that into a set of span tags. So I'm suggesting that you capture the paragraph and then just remove any embedded tag data. This new value is what I'd insert into your span tags

Comment: I definitely need to keep tag data so links, images, etc...work within paragraphs.